# Not able to add matrix rows after 99 rows

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I am not able to add more than 99 rows in my matrix field though I have already set Maximum rows to 1000, not sure whats happening.
 Is it a **BUG** or **LIMIT** of matrix field type?

EE version : 2.6.1
Matrix version : 2.5.6

Note : Its an old project so cant take risk of upgrading EE or matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix doesn’t have any built-in limits, but PHP has a configurable limit on how many values that it will check in POST ([max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)). Try adjusting that.